# Hyperlink spacing within justified text

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, text-align, justify

`Text-align:justify` doesn't seem to space out hyperlinks the way it spaces out regular text. This means that if I use no hyperlinks, the text looks fine with no awkward spaces, but if I add hyperlinks, new awkward white spaces are required to fill the gaps left by the un-spaced-out hyperlink text. Is there any way to fix this? You can see what I mean by checking out what I have so far here: [www.laborcrib.com](http://www.laborcrib.com) (awkward gaps around the hyperlinks)

This is the only styling for my text:

```
    article {
    font-size: 19px;
    max-width: 650px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    padding: 20px;
    line-height:33px;   
    text-align: justify;
    color: #383737;
}
```

[This is only my second post so let me know if there's anything I can do to improve this question--I've searched for similar questions and I've tried to be as specific as possible]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a style that is adding `a {padding: 0px 28px 0px 28px;}` for your links in the `<style>` section in the `<head>` of `index.html`. Look for line 49 of index.html.

It may be possible that this was intended to be scoped to some other `a` tags (perhaps navigation?), but it is applying to all of them.

In addition your normalize.css isn't loading as it is getting a 404 not found error.

If you wanted to keep that spacing for the three links at the top below the title you could add either a `class` or an `id` to the `<div>` that encloses them and modify the rule so that it applied to only those three links. e.g. `<div class="toplinks">...` and `.toplinks a { padding...`

Comment: If the padding is set to 0 the problem is indeed solved

Comment: Ah! Perfect, you were absolutely right. Any suggestions for how, next time, I might be able to spot this myself? I want to one day develop your speed and keenness in spotting such things.

Comment: I was browsing with Chrome and right clicked on a link on your page and selected `inspect element` and then looked at all the css rules that were being applied until I saw the one with the paddding. Then I checked to see the impact of that rule by removing the checkmark from the box to the left of the rule. I saw the location of the rule to the right of the rule, and then used view page source to visually verify the location and see how the page was structured. There was a notification of error which is what pointed out the 404 that I mentioned for `normalize.css`.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the 28px right and left padding from the anchor element I think the anchor tag text is consistently justified with the rest of the text (at least in Chrome & IE 10).  There are a couple of places where anchor tags could use a single space before it - "the website" and "nabbed their first grammy" links in particular, but those aren't CSS issues.